# How to create Waterfall/Timeline of a Website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, timeline, waterfall

How I can create Waterfall/Timeline of Website like Chrome Inspector, GTMetrix?

I need to get datas while website is opening. How much request did browser while loading all of website. Where the request happend etc.

Is there any library or npm module to do this?

Thanks, have a good life :)

Comment: If you want software recommendations, ask here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe "pace" is what you need?

```
$ npm install pace
```

You can search for it online.

Comment: Looking for it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following library:

https://github.com/NUKnightLab/TimelineJS

Comment: This looks good but, I need to get datas while website is opening. How much request did browser while loading all of website. Where the request happend etc